# Focus on search bar when I open master

Tags: sapui5

I have a master-detail app (SplitContainer in *HideMode*)

In my master page I have a list item with a search input on the top. From any page if I open the master I have always the same master list page.

**I would like that when I open the master the focus go to the search input**. In this mode the user does not have to click on input to start write but is already there

Can I do the same when I open a SelectDialog? https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.SelectDialog/samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution. thanks @cobeete
In the `onInit` function of my master page I have written:

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("splitApp").attachAfterMasterOpen(function () {
            sap.ui.getCore().byId("UniversalMenu--searchItemFiled").focus();
});
```

where `splitApp` is my [sap.m.SplitApp](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.SplitApp.html) ,  `UniversalMenu` is the master page that include the search field `searchItemFiled`

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the focus handling when your master controller is initialized or when the after show event is fired.
Example:

```
sap.ui.controller("com.view.Master", {

    onInit: function() {
        this.getView().addEventDelegate({
            onAfterShow: function(oEvent) {
                //focus handling
                sap.ui.getCore().byId("searchFieldId").focus();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Yes, you can do the same in a SelectDialog control.

See: [SAPUI5 - Implementing Focus Handling](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/91f19f036f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html)